Is it possible to supply power to Raspberry Pi 4 using gnd on pin 9?
I need to power the Raspberry Pi 4 using GPIO pins. In most cases, people do this using 2 or 4 pins for 5V and 6 pins for GND. But the 6th pin is already occupied for cooling, and it is difficult to replace it, because the connector is dual with a voltage of 5 V.
Can I use the 9th pin for GND for Raspberry instead of the 6th? Or maybe any other GND pin? Is it designed for this?


Can I use the 9th pin for GND for Raspberry instead of the 6th? Or maybe any other GND pin? Is it designed for this?

Yes - GND is GND (or Ground is Ground... or Ground is GND :)
All Ground pins are interchangeable, just as the two 5V pins are interchangeable. The only advantage of using multiple headers for Ground (or 5V) is that the overall resistance is decreased slightly.
